# how to finish multiple instances of an activity at once in android

Tags: android-manifest

The activities in stack are A,B1,B2,B3,B4. if i press back button in B4(activity) i should finish all the instances of B activity and it should take me to  the A activity.

Answer (score 1):

On B4 you should call the below method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class)
 .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
 return;
}
```

Comment: Paresh Mayani,Thanks alot, but in this case it is clearing all the activities including 'A' activity also. here we are restarting the A activity .. I want to clear only the instances of B activity(B1,B2,B3,B4).. how do i do that..